# Not able to take db backup in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-backups, ssms

This seems very odd asking simple question but I am really blank what to do.

I want to take database backup from SQL Server 2012 Management Studio using the steps is show in image

[image: database>>task>>backup..]

This is the window appear when clicking on backup..

[image]

but actually in my local disk I don't have the path in the destination box.

I am unable to create new location either.

i tried creating folders as in destination box but again I am getting below error

[image]

- The operating system I am using is window 8
- The SQL Server Management Studio I am using is 2012
- the local server is SQL Server 2005
- the remote server version is SQL Server 2012

Please guys help me...

Comment: Did you try to remove all paths from Destination box and add a new real one?

Comment: Have you tried remove all but one in the destination box. Seems like you can have only one destination at a time.

Comment: yes i tried removing all paths and gave my own path. but i am not able to browse the location. If i manually type the path and gave the path still i am getting same error...

Answer (score 0):

SSMS thinks your trying to split your backup in to both the locations. Try to delete both, using the remove button, then hit add, and add your destination for the backup, or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Ha ha found the issue.

I was creating the backup using sqlserver 2012 and trying to import using sql server 2005. Upgraded my sql server and it is working like charm...